# Dawes Galaxy OLN and horizontal dropouts

Tags: frames, internally-geared-hub, dropouts

I want to build up a steel framed commuter/light tourer/utility bike with hub gears.

A Dawes Galaxy from the 1990s era looks about right to provide the frame.

But I want 135mm rear dropout spacing (for hub gears) AND semi horizontal dropout (for chain tension).

Looking at bikes I'm getting the feeling that I can't get both. It looks like Dawes went to 135mm OLN at the same time as they went to vertical dropouts. I think all 8 speed (and above) rear cassettes were 135mm.

Anybody shed any light on this? Thakns

Comment: 135 is the standard for 8/9/10 QR mountain hubs, and is also used by most hybrids, touring bikes, and disc road. Conventional modern road is 130.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

- Find an older steel frame and [spread the frame](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html#spreading).
- Buy a different frame, such as a [Surly Cross-check](http://surlybikes.com/bikes/cross_check/frame_highlights).

Comment: Thanks. I meant specifically the Dawes Galaxy. If there's a version with semi horizontal dropouts AND a 135 OLN

Comment: @MikeyMo - Why not spread the frame by cold setting?

Answer (score 1):

According to Sheldon Brown it is possible to adjust the width of the hub by replacing some of the nuts with thinner ones

```
The Shimano 8-speed hubs have a overlocknut spacing ranging of 132 to 135 mm, as sold: see Shimano's overlocknut spacing chart. It is possible to reduce the spacing of the Nexus Rollerbrake/freewheeling models to as little as 126 mm by leaving off the Rollerbrake and using a narrower locknut.
```

http://www.sheldonbrown.com/nexus8.shtml

However I would agree that cold setting it to 135mm would be easier.  Dawes Galaxy bikes are built to last and I'm sure it wouldn't be bothered by a bit of stretching

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've read Sheldon's comment. As he said though, it removes some of the weather protection, and as you probably know, some of the Nexus hubs have a reputation for railing through water getting in.

And actually, I may want to use a roller brake. I've got them another bike and I think they're OK.

Spoke to somebody at Bob Jackson. I think they know about bike frames. Cold setting 5 mm is OK, more than that you're into new brake bridges etc. By that point I may as well just get them to make me a frame to my specs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks. Some Dawes Galaxies have 135 OLN, some have horizontal dropouts, I'm trying to find if there are any that are both. I suppose I'm hoping for answers from Galaxy owners.